# How to find the highest card in Poker in C++?

Tags: c++

```
card highCard ()
{
    card highest_card;
    int number=0;

    for (int i =0; i <5; i++)
    {
        if (_cards[i].getRankValue > number)
        {
            number = _cards[i].getRankValue;
            highest_card = _cards[i];
        }
        return highest_card;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or more like, what I am doing. I am suppose to find the highest card in my hand (including the suit and rank) for a game in poker.

Comment: It is basically impossible for anyone to help you with so little information.  Please see http://sscce.org/ .  Remember to state the inputs to the program, the expected output, the actual output, and the results of the troubleshooting you have already done.

Comment: You return after the first card even if you didn't enter the if. Replace this whole thing with `std::max_element` based on `Card::getRankValue` (which is an odd data member naming convention).

Comment: Paying attention to your compiler warnings, in this case not-all-control-paths-return, would solve this for you.

Answer (score 5):

What you have looks perfectly fine, except you are returning too early. You want to return after looking at all the cards in the hand. As you have it now, your function will only look at _cards[0] before returning.

```
card highCard ()
{
  card highest_card;
  int number=0;

  for (int i =0; i <5; i++)
  {
     if (_cards[i].getRankValue > number)
     {
         number = _cards[i].getRankValue;
         highest_card = _cards[i];
     }    
  }
  return highest_card;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're returning the card in the for loop. Basically, the code is running the loop at i=0 and then returning it right after- it never runs the code when i is 1 or above. Put the return line after the for loop so you ensure the program runs through all the cards before returning the highest card.